# Can't find SVG element on google calender (python)

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, svg

I'm trying to delete an event on google agenda. But every time I get an error saying the webdriver can't find the element.
[image of element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxtk8.png)

```
Exception has occurred: TimeoutException
Message: 
  File "C:\Users\cuyve\Desktop\git\ss-tasks\google_agenda_API.py", line 105, in delete_event
    delete = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/span/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/span/svg")))
```

I tried using different selectors but it didn't work
this is my code i have for this:

```
delete = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/span/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/span/svg")))
delete.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xpath cannot locate an `svg` elements in the normal approach.

Instead of:

```
//svg
```

You need to use:

```
//*[name()='svg']
```

You should also try to steer away from hard coded xpaths. Any change on any part of the page down your current path (*and it's a long path*) and it will break.

For your google calendar you can use this:

```
//div[@data-tooltip='Delete event']//*[name()='svg']
```

That matches a single unique identifier like so:
[image: devtools xpath]

Comment: thank you the driver found the element but it won't click it. There is no error message but just nothing happens

Comment: @Arnz3 - try a webdriver wait to ensure the object is ready and clickable or try another identifier :-)  -  This question is a few weeks old now you might want to consider asking a new question to get more support

Comment: I found the problem it's just selenium won't click elements if u use name() in the identifier i fixed it with  //div[@data-tooltip="Afspraak verwijderen"]//*[@class=" NMm5M"]